# get github issues by their ids through graphql endpoints

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I am trying to get the list of issues by their ids from Github using graphql, but looks like I am missing something or its not possible.

```graphql
query ($ids:['517','510']!) {
  repository(owner:"owner", name:"repo") {
    issues(last:20, states:CLOSED) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          url
          body
          author{
            login
          }
          labels(first:5) {
            edges {
              node {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query is giving me response as below,

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Parse error on \"'\" (error) at [1, 14]",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 14
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Kindly help me identify if its possible or that I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) in order to build a single request requesting multiple `issue` object :

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "material-ui", owner: "mui-org") {
    issue1: issue(number: 2) {
      title
      createdAt
    }
    issue2: issue(number: 3) {
      title
      createdAt
    }
    issue3: issue(number: 10) {
      title
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository%28name%3A%20%22material-ui%22%2C%20owner%3A%20%22mui-org%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20issue1%3A%20issue%28number%3A%202%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20issue2%3A%20issue%28number%3A%203%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20issue3%3A%20issue%28number%3A%2010%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

which gives :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issue1": {
        "title": "Support for ref's on Input component",
        "createdAt": "2014-10-15T15:49:13Z"
      },
      "issue2": {
        "title": "Unable to pass onChange event to Input component",
        "createdAt": "2014-10-15T16:23:28Z"
      },
      "issue3": {
        "title": "Is it possible for me to make this work if I'm using React version 0.12.0?",
        "createdAt": "2014-10-30T14:11:59Z"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This request can also be simplified using [fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments) to prevent repetition:

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "material-ui", owner: "mui-org") {
    issue1: issue(number: 2) {
      ...IssueFragment
    }
    issue2: issue(number: 3) {
      ...IssueFragment
    }
    issue3: issue(number: 10) {
      ...IssueFragment
    }
  }
}

fragment IssueFragment on Issue {
  title
  createdAt
}
```

The request can be built programmatically, such as in this example [python](/questions/tagged/python) script :

```python
import requests

token = "YOUR_TOKEN"
issueIds = [2,3,10]
repoName = "material-ui"
repoOwner = "mui-org"

query = """
query($name: String!, $owner: String!) {
  repository(name: $name, owner: $owner) {
    %s
  }
}

fragment IssueFragment on Issue {
  title
  createdAt
}
"""

issueFragments = "".join([
    """
    issue%d: issue(number: %d) {
      ...IssueFragment
    }""" % (t,t) for t in issueIds
])
r = requests.post("https://api.github.com/graphql",
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
    },
    json = {
        "query": query % issueFragments,
        "variables": {
            "name": repoName,
            "owner": repoOwner
        }
    }
)
print(r.json()["data"]["repository"])
```

Comment: This works like a charm. I have used the graphql query, since i am working in java, I will make the implementation in java. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can fetch for `issues` and pass in an array of integers for their `id`s.

But you can search for a single issue by `id` like so (this works for me)

```
query ($n: Int!) {
  repository(owner:"owner", name:"repo-name") {
    issue (number: $n) {
      state
      title
      author {
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where `$n` is `{"n": <your_number>}` defined.

If you have an array of `id`s, then you can just make multiple queries to GitHub.

Sadly, with this approach, you cannot specify what the `state` of the issue to be. But I think the logic is that once you know the issue Id, you shouldn't care what state it is, since you have that exact id.

Comment: yes, there are limitations on the github api to not allow filtering issues by their ids

Comment: I do not prefer individual calls and instead use @Bertrand Martel answer