# How to get all comments along with issues with github graphql

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I'am trying this [get github issues by their ids through graphql endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266788/get-github-issues-by-their-ids-through-graphql-endpoints)

And tried this code

```
{
  repository(name: "reponame", owner: "ownername") {
    issue1: issue(number: 2) {
      title
      createdAt
    }
    issue2: issue(number: 3) {
      title
      createdAt
    }
    issue3: issue(number: 10) {
      title
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

With this, I am able to get back the title, but I am also trying to get all of the comments of the issue. I tried adding `comments` to the above code, but it didn't work.

I want to modify the above code only.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GraphQL, you have to select every scalar field that you want. So far, you have selected the scalar fields of `Issue.title` and `Issue.createdAt`. Comments, however, are not "scalar values" -- they're objects -- so to get anything out of them, you have to request deeply into the objects all the way to the scalar values.

Additionally, Comments are a [paginated connection](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/overview/), so you also have to define how many you want back and go deep into the connection to get to the "node", which is the object you actually want:

```
query {
  repository(name:"reponame", owner: "ownername") {
    issue(number: 2) {
      title
      createdAt
      # first 10 results
      comments(first: 10) {
        # edges.node is where the actual `Comment` object is
        edges {
          node {
            author {
              avatarUrl
            }
            body
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```